# How can I fill a serie of dates with 0 value_counts()?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am counting how many times repeat a date in an excel sheet (filtering by month), but in the cases that the date doesnt exist, i want to fill it with a 0 in the value_counts() function. Then i need to plot it.

Imagine that is a bunch of trucks dispatching some product:2022-07-04 i have only 1 truck, and then 2022-07-06 I have another, but 2022-07-05 doesnt exist, so it was 0 trucks that day (see picture)

```
df_log_mel['Elecmetal Date'].loc()

july_log_mel = df_log_mel['Elecmetal Date'][2340:2378].value_counts(sort=False)

july_log_mel
```

Result:

```
2022-07-01    1
2022-07-02    2
2022-07-03    2
2022-07-04    1
2022-07-06    1
2022-07-07    1
2022-07-08    1
2022-07-09    2
2022-07-10    1
2022-07-11    1
2022-07-14    2
2022-07-15    1
2022-07-16    1
2022-07-17    2
2022-07-18    2
2022-07-19    2
2022-07-20    2
2022-07-21    2
2022-07-23    1
2022-07-24    1
2022-07-25    1
2022-07-26    1
2022-07-27    2
2022-07-29    2
2022-07-30    2
2022-07-31    1
Name: Elecmetal Date, dtype: int64
```

[dates value_counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRK9s.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can `reindex` your Series with `date_range`:

```
s = df['date'].value_counts()

s = s.reindex(pd.date_range(s.index.min(), s.index.max(), freq='D')
                .strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
              fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
2022-07-04    2
2022-07-05    0
2022-07-06    1
2022-07-07    0
2022-07-08    1
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

used input:

```
         date
0  2022-07-04
1  2022-07-04
2  2022-07-06
3  2022-07-08
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want daily value counts, use `asfreq` and `fillna`:

```
july_log_mel.index = pd.to_datetime(july_log_mel.index)
july_log_mel.asfreq('D').fillna(0)
```